# Django Admin additional custom field is hidden

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to show the image src, as a field tag in Django Admin and I have:

```
class AImageAdmin(AdminFilteringFK, AdminListImageModel, admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = AImage
    list_display = ('image_tag', 'a', 'filename', 'file_type')
    fields = ('a', 'image', 'image_tag', 'filename', 'file_type')
    readonly_fields = ('filename', 'file_type', 'image_tag')

 def image_tag(self, obj):

    src = obj.image.url

    return mark_safe(
        '<img src="{url}" />'.format(url=src))
```

The new field is created correctly, but for some reasons (that I don't get Django is hiding the field, by adding "display: none")

```
  <img src="/media/a/28/image/at_2_zxkm.gif" style="display: none !important;" width="70;/">
```

Comment: Which Django version that you use? it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def image_tag(self, 
    return '<img src="%s" />' % (obj.image.url)
image_tag.allow_tags = True
image_tag.short_description = 'Image'
```

Comment: I use Django 2.0, the allow_tags is deprecated